# How can i group field using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i'm having an issue creating a query with mysql, i have this rows:
[image]

and i would like the result will be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "value": "VERTICAL_DESIGN_SOFT_MATERIAL",
    "images": [
      {
        "color": "white",
        "image": "http://localhost/white.png"
      },
      {
        "color": "black",
        "image": "http://localhost/black.png"
      },
      {
        "color": "gray",
        "image": "http://localhost/gray.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "VERTICAL_DESIGN_HARD_MATERIAL",
    "images": [
      {
        "color": "blanco",
        "image": "http://localhost/blanco.png"
      },
      {
        "color": "black",
        "image": "http://localhost/black.png"
      },
      {
        "color": "gray",
        "image": "http://localhost/gray.png"
      },
      {
        "color": "azul",
        "image": "http://localhost/o_azul.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i show it like a json because i think this describes what i need, i would like to group color and image in a field to access that rows, i've tried using group by but i cant get it,

i tried something like this:

```
SELECT v_ebt,colors,image FROM `am_mm_baggage_select_2` group by colors, image
```

could you please help me?

regards
Mario

Comment: Issues of data display are normally resolved in application code

Comment: Please show what sql you try ...

Comment: Your sample data and desired results really have nothing to do with each other, so it is unclear what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would really help.  Also, be clear on the formats you want.  Are you specifically looking for a JSON result set?

Comment: @Dri372 i use this: SELECT v_ebt,colors,image FROM `am_mm_baggage_select_2` group by colors, image

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff i'm not looking a json result it was just to explaint how i would like to get those fields, inside a field or a var append colors and image

Comment: > i would like to get those fields, inside a field ... not clear shown sampla data and expected output in tables, best using this tool http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Why would you need to transpose data into one column and prefix with strings? Edit question to show desired output as a text table, not json code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just combine colors and image fields:

```
SELECT v_ebt, CONCAT("color: ", colors, "; image: ", image) AS Data FROM table;
```

To get all data vertically in one column and still allow ordering by common identifier, consider:

```
SELECT 1 AS Srt, v_ebt AS Grp, v_ebt AS Data FROM docs
UNION SELECT 2, v_ebt, CONCAT("color: ", colors, ", image: ", image) 
     FROM docs
ORDER BY Grp, Srt;
```

If you want to concatenate multiple rows of data into a single string, explore GROUP_CONCAT function.

```
SELECT v_ebt, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("color: ", colors, ", image: ", image, Char(10)+Char(13))
                           ORDER BY CONCAT("color: ", colors, ", image: ", image, Char(10)+Char(13))) AS list
FROM table
GROUP BY v_ebt;
```

Can't get fiddle to work with Char(10) + Char(13) nor concatenation with `+` and I don't have MySQL to test but hopefully this gets you started.

Then instead of trying to do this within query, there is the option of creating a report that will sort and group by v_ebt data. This would be simple in Access and I expect MySQL reporting tools and Crystal Reports could do it.