# Repeated column on inner join select query

Tags: sql

I have small problem here I have two table with primary key and foreign key

Like this: Table 1 with primary key

```
Id   PK
novelname
description
Date
```

And table 2 with foreign key

```
Id   auto increment
Chaptername 
Chapternumber
Content 
Chapter_id  FK
```

I use the join query:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON Table1.id = table2.chapter_id 
WHERE Table1.id = 0 
  AND Table2.chapter_id = 0
```

In table1 there is one novelname but in table2 there is multiple chapters and the novelname get repeat with every chaptername how do I remove the repeated novelname and display just one novelname with multiple chaptername

The output in the page is like this

I have 3 chapter in the same novel and it displayed like this

```
novelname
Chapter 1

novelname
Chapter 2

novelname 
Chapter 3
```

The expected output would be:

```
Novelname 

Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will help greatly if you edit your question to include sample data (and lay it out as tables) and also your expected output as well as the erroneous output.

Comment: that depends  what result you want, a [mre] is for such things very helpful

Comment: That's not really how joins work. It's not an Excel spreadsheet, it's pairing up every novel with its chapters

Comment: I *assume* the problem is that you are using `*`. **Define** the columns you want.

Comment: I've also removed the conflicting tags; only tag the RDBMS you are **really** using.

Comment: So all I want to display one novelname with it multichapters how do I remove the repeation

Comment: @Larnu, issue has nothing to do with using `*`. Issue is OP wants to do something queries are not intended for. Either build a report and design it to not repeat the novel name (chapters will still be vertical) or concatenate the chapters into a single string. How the latter is accomplished depends on database used as well as the GUI interface.

Comment: Please mention your dbms and it's version.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946148/how-can-i-group-field-using-mysql/67952867#67952867

Comment: Some kind of group_concat, depending on the dbms.

Comment: I work with xampp I didn't really know the version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2017 or newer version then you can use string_agg() to get the chapter names as comma separated string in a column for each novel.

```
SELECT   table1.novelname , string_agg(table2.Chaptername,',') FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN  table2 ON Table1.id = table2.chapter_id  WHERE Table1.id = 0  
group by table1.novelname
```

For MySQL it will be:

```
 SELECT   table1.novelname , group_concat(table2.Chaptername,',') FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN  table2 ON Table1.id = table2.chapter_id  WHERE Table1.id = 0  
    group by table1.novelname
```

Comment: Can you display result with this statment

Comment: No the the selection query didn't work any other suggestions

Comment: For MySQL it's group_concat()